# Is there a way for a getter to return specific dictionary entries<string, someClass> based on a list of strings?

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

In my WPF application i'm trying to retrieve only specific dictionary entries based on a list of keys that the user can edit.

I'm trying to go about this by having a `List<string> ListOfKeys` that the user can modify, a `Dictionary<string, AnObject> AllObjects` that contains a bunch of AnObjects with different variables, and a `Dictionary<string, AnObject> SomeObjects` with a `get{ }` containing a query to only return the entries from `AllObjects` where the key in `AllObjects` matches an entry in the `ListOfKey`s.

What do i put in the query to make this work?
Additionally, any suggestions for another way i should go about this?

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObjects.Values}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding someText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#

```
public class AClass
{
    string someText;
    int someNumber
    [...] etc.
}

public Dictionary<string, AClass> AllObjects;

public List<string> ListOfKeys;

public Dictionary<string, AClass> SomeObjects
{
    get
    {
        return AllObjects.Where(a key in AllObjects matches an entry in the ListOfKeys);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with binding filtered `List<AClass>` instead?

Comment: That's actually a far better idea. Still wouldn't know how to filter that list though.

Comment: AllObjects. where ( ListOfKeys contains item.fieldConnectedWithKey)

Comment: AllObjects.Where(x => ListOfKeys.Contains(x.Key));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to a list instead of a dictionary:

```
List<AClass> someObjects
get
{
    return AllObjects.Where(x => ListOfKeys.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).toList();
}
```